# How to grep Multi line pattern from LogFolder using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a requirement to capture json request from a server log files.
The log directory has lot of server.log files of daily basis. I need to grep selective json from logFile based on the keyword.

**Received request with content** is my keyword in Server.log files

How do I retrieve selected json based on the keyword mentioned? For the below mentioned code, only first line is getting printed. How do i print the complete JSON?

**Code**

```
import glob, os,re
os.chdir("N:/HERE/jboss-eap-7.1.0/jboss-eap-7.1/standalone/log")

for file in glob.glob("server.log.2020-08-07"):
    print(file)

pattern = "Received request with content"

file = open("server.log.2020-08-07", "r")
for line in file:
    if re.search(pattern, line,re.M):
        print(line)
```

**Current Output**

```
2020-08-07 20:45:16,696 DEBUG [org.kie.server.remote.rest.drools.CommandResource] (default task-38) Received request with content '{
```

**Expected Output**

```
2020-08-07 20:45:16,696 DEBUG [org.kie.server.remote.rest.drools.CommandResource] (default task-33) Received request with content '{
    "lookup": "stateless",
    "commands": [{
            "insert": {
                "out-identifier": "PolicyOutput",
                "return-object": false,
                "entry-point": "DEFAULT",
                "object": {
                    "com.Testing.sampleproject.PercentageCalculation": {

                        "total_Sales_Of_Latest_Year": 1000,
                        "total_Sales_Of_Previous_Year": 9000,
                        "pbdit": 0,
                        "turnover": 0,
                        "cash_Profit_Of_Latest_Year": 0,
                        "cash_Profit_Of_Previous_Year": 0,
                        "pat_Sales_Of_Latest_Year": 0
                        }
                    }   } }]
}'
```

**Server.log File**

```
2020-08-07 20:36:29,897 DEBUG [org.kie.server.remote.rest.drools.CommandResource] (default task-33) Received request with content '{
    "lookup": "stateless",
    "commands": [{
            "insert": {
                "out-identifier": "PolicyOutput",
                "return-object": false,
                "entry-point": "DEFAULT",
                "object": {
                    "com.Testing.sampleproject.PercentageCalculation": {
                        "total_Sales_Of_Latest_Year": 1000,
                        "total_Sales_Of_Previous_Year": 9000,
                        "pbdit": 0,
                        "turnover": 0,
                        "cash_Profit_Of_Latest_Year": 0,
                        "cash_Profit_Of_Previous_Year": 0,
                        "pat_Sales_Of_Latest_Year": 0
                        }
                    }   } }]
}'
2020-08-07 20:36:29,899 DEBUG [org.kie.server.services.impl.locator.LatestContainerLocator] (default task-33) Searching for latest container for alias SampleProject within available containers [KieContainerResource [containerId=SampleProject_1.0.1-SNAPSHOT, releaseId=com.Testing:SampleProject:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT, resolvedReleaseId=com.Testing:SampleProject:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT, status=STARTED], KieContainerResource [containerId=SampleProject_1.0.2-SNAPSHOT, releaseId=com.Testing:SampleProject:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT, resolvedReleaseId=com.Testing:SampleProject:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT, status=STARTED]]
2020-08-07 20:36:46,807 DEBUG [org.kie.server.controller.impl.KieServerInstanceManager] (Thread-139) Using client provider org.kie.server.controller.websocket.client.WebSocketKieServerClientProvider@56675f4a
2020-08-07 20:36:46,807 DEBUG [org.kie.server.controller.impl.KieServerInstanceManager] (Thread-139) Using client org.kie.server.controller.websocket.client.WebSocketKieServerClient@404d94c0
2020-08-07 21:36:29,897 DEBUG [org.kie.server.remote.rest.drools.CommandResource] (default task-33) Received request with content '{
    "lookup": "stateless",
    "commands": [{
            "insert": {
                "out-identifier": "PolicyOutput",
                "return-object": false,
                "entry-point": "DEFAULT",
                "object": {
                    "com.Testing.sampleproject.PercentageCalculation": {

                        "total_Sales_Of_Latest_Year": 1000,
                        "total_Sales_Of_Previous_Year": 9000,
                        "pbdit": 0,
                        "turnover": 0,
                        "cash_Profit_Of_Latest_Year": 0,
                        "cash_Profit_Of_Previous_Year": 0,
                        "pat_Sales_Of_Latest_Year": 0
                        }
                    }   } }]
}'
```

Comment: Could you provide some samples of the actual file you want to parse? Please include examples where you want to skip certain rows, and multiple objects that you want to capture.

Comment: @HampusLarsson I have edited the post. Attached log file as well. I need to retrieve only json part from the log file

Answer (score 0):

Following is a way you can get your complete json with one assumption number of lines of json is known

```
with open("server.log", "r") as fd:
    lines=fd.readlines()
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if re.search(pattern, line, re.M):
            print(i)
            for op_json_line in lines[i:i+18]:
                print(op_json_line)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but Request is dynamic in nature. Can't hardcode number of lines.